Serializing binary expression into a string without parentheses
Those both expressions are parsed as a binary expression
3 - (4 + 5)
3 - (4 * 5)

When given only an AST, how do I know that in the second expression when serializing to a string the parentheses can be dropped? Should I somehow rely on operator precendece?
Say for 3 - (4 + 5) I have this AST:
{
  type: BinaryExpression,
  left: {
    type: Literal,
    value: 3,
  },
  operator: '-',
  right: {
    type: BinaryExpression,
    left: {
      type: Literal,
      value: 4,
    },
    operator: '+',
    right: {
      type: Literal,
      value: 5,
    }
  }
};

For 3 - (4 * 5) it looks exactly the same, except for different operator in the inner BinaryExpression.
Both - and + have the same operator precendence, while * has higher one, so I could say that if the precendence between right and left operator is differnt I can drop the parentheses?
const parentBinaryExpPrecedence = getPrecedence(expression.operator)
const childBinaryExpPrecedence = getPrecedence(expression.right.operator)

const dropParentheses = parentBinaryExpPrecedence !== childBinaryExpPrecedence 


In the AST, the operators are not really "right" and "left", but more like "parent" and "child". You need a set of rules that answers the question for each pair of operators in such situations. As to the "precedence of the entire expression", I have no clue what that means. Precedence relative to what?

thanks, https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/playground gives me "left" and "right", but maybe it's just a convention? regarding "precedence of the entire expression", I meant that for example in the example I gave there's only one operator + or *, but I could have more, like "4 + 5 - 3", so I thought I'd need to know the precendence for all those operators, but maybe what you're saying is that this bigger expression on the right will still be split into binary expression and I can check only its operator?

mathjs   https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/tree/develop/src   has a simplify method, and it will remove unused brackets.  It's maybe doing a lot more than you require, but you could maybe check out it's code.  It uses Expression trees, so I believe similar to AST's in this regard.

@MaxKoretskyi well there are lots of ways to build something like an AST, depending on what you need to actually do with it. It does not have to be a tree, but because of how most parsers operate on source text a simple binary tree is a common choice.

@Keith, seems pretty complicated to figure it out.

@Pointy, understand, but any suggestions how to achieve what I need?

I updated the question with more details of what I'm trying to achieve

You can drop parentheses around a left or right subexpression if the operator of the subexpression has higher precedence than the operator of the entire expression. But that might still leave some unnecessary parentheses, as in 3 + (4 + 5).

@HeikoTheißen, thanks, so in my case it would be const dropParentheses = parentBinaryExpPrecedence < childBinaryExpPrecedence, correct?

@HeikoTheißen also important (required) to take into account commutativity; in the + and - case, the operators have the same precedence (well, most people would say they do) but parentheses are still required.\

expression.operator.right,  did you mean expression.right.operator  ?

@Keith, yes, corrected it, thnak

@Pointy Actually, I think that's associativity, not commutativity. + and - are left-associative, so 3 - 4 + 5  is parsed as (3 - 4) + 5

@Barmar yea but 3 - 5 and 5 - 3 are not the same. I am not a formalist however so I could be completely wrong.

@Pointy True, but who said anything about reordering expressions? I thought it was just about removing parentheses.

Well in 3 + (4 + 5) you don't need the parens, but in 3 - (4 + 5) you do. (wait; do you? I haven't had enough sleep.)

And that's because addition is associative ((3 + 4) + 5 == 3 + (4 + 5)), not commutativity.

yea. 3 - (4 + 5) does need parens, otherwise it'd be 4 not -6.  In any case the point for this question is that there has to be a set of rules so that traversing the AST (or whatever gets built during the parse) can know the algebraic notation rules and spit out the right text.

@Barmar so what rule should I define for myself based on HeikoTheißen's suggestion but taking associativity into account like you suggested?

@Pointy, has to be a set of rules, right, but what you're saying is that one rule suggested by HeikoTheißen here is not enough?
